# --spinnaker-registry flag override not effective

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

we are using spinnaker version 1.6.1.. when we try to override the dockerRegistry using the --spinnaker-registry flag in the InstallHalyard.sh script, the registry is still not overridden.. its still referring to the public registry..

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Just found the solution at the Spinnaker Slack Channel "halyard"

- Link to the slack message: https://spinnakerteam.slack.com/archives/C3YBRLG8H/p1540378395000100
- Service setting link, referenced in the screenshot: https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/custom/#custom-service-settings